# Javascript eventListener of scroll dosen't work

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, scrollbar

I added an **eventListener** of '**scroll**' to an element and it's not working.

If I use **onscroll="myFunction()"** on the **p** tag and then I access it, it works just fine.

Where is the problem?

Thanks!

```js
const myDiv = document.querySelector('#hScroll')
const customInfo = document.querySelector('#customInfo')

console.log(customInfo)

customInfo.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    console.log('yup');
})
```

```html
<div id="hScroll" class="container-fluid asd position-relative ps-3 pe-3 fadeEndB fadeStartB">
  <p id="customInfo" class="custom-info overflow-auto">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I'm using **VUE js** and my HTML tag was defined into the **div** with the id of **#app** and aparently VUE js, somehow, deactivates the *addEventListener* if you do like this.

**SOLUTION**

I put my **javascript** into **VUE mounted()** and it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

because no scrolling events, occurs in your element (which is P)

try this code and you will findout what I mean.

```js
const myDiv = document.querySelector('#hScroll')
const customInfo = document.querySelector('#customInfo')

console.log(customInfo)

customInfo.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    console.log('yup');
})
```

```html
<p id="customInfo" class="custom-info overflow-auto" style="width:60px; height:60px; overflow-y:auto">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
  </p>
```

Comment: Ok. But how I can fix it? I don't want to use 'onscroll=myFunction'.

Comment: you just dont need "onscroll". what I wrote is just based on eventListner.

my question is, you want to do something while page reach to your P element or when you scroll inside your P element?

Comment: When I scroll inside P element, I want something to happened.

Comment: As I mentioned, You have to make your P element, scrollable >
style="width:60px; height:60px; overflow-y:auto"

Or use Wheel Event if you dont want to overflow your Element

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent

Comment: I tried with your line of code, but still not working.

const customInfo = document.getElementById('customInfo');

customInfo.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    console.log('yup');
})

Comment: i've edited my reply
run code and see 'yup' will shows up when you scroll in P element

Answer (score -1):

The callback function has to take an event parameter.

```
customInfo.addEventListener('scroll', (ev) => {
    console.log('yup');
})
```

Comment: Can you create a [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993) to show that adding the parameter fixes the issue? (Because I highly doubt it makes any difference.)

Comment: It doesn't make any difference.